# screenshot handler (Print-Screen) problem

Tags: print-screen

At 1st I installed the main Ubuntu distro 23.04 and I really liked the built in screenshot handler solution.
But I shifted to the "Ubuntu Studio" 23.04 and the screenshot handler of this is really bad.
I would like to install or utilize that schreenshot handler of main Ubuntu distro on the "Ubuntu Studio" edition.
Is it possible? How can I do it? How to figure out the exact name of screenshot handler of the main Ubuntu?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: press "prnt scr sys req" button on the kb

Comment: This is not an answer. Beleive or not, I pressed that key. My problem is quite different. Read the/any question before you write anything. Thank you!